# Sonarqube error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel cannot be cast to org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Hi I wrote own plugin for sonar 5.1.2 based on some checks from java-web-plugin 3.5 (dependency in pom for java-checks 3.5) and when I try to run analysis on project i get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel cannot be cast to org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel
    at org.sonar.java.checks.SubscriptionBaseVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionBaseVisitor.java:32)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:94)
    ... 38 more
```

for example i copied to my plugin code from BadMethodName_S00100_Check.java and changed only class name, description and issue info. Why am I getting error? Other checks which don't use semanticModel works just fine.

Comment: We cannot answer specifically based on the information provided.  I can say, however, that you can always cast an instance of a class to that same class.  The exception message therefore indicates that you have two different classes with the same name, which can happen if they are loaded by different `ClassLoader`s.  Why that might arise is highly dependent on the context in which your code is running.

Comment: Thanks John. In directory extensions/plugins I put my own_plugin.jar (uses java-squid 3.5) and sonar-java-plugin-3.5.jar but problem occurs only for those checks that use SemanticModel. I need both jars. How can I solve it?

Comment: Unless you've copied the class file for `org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel` into your own JAR, the problem is unlikely to be where you place jars or which jars you make available.  Since you mentioned java-plugin-web, though, I *speculate* that inside an applet you are trying to use a `SemanticModel` object somehow generated outside that applet, or *vise versa*.  But that's just a guess; you still haven't given us much to go on.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the class SemanticModel is not designed to be used in custom rules and is not part of the API. As such, you are encountering an error at runtime as this class is not made available whereas we can't "forbid" you to use it during compilation. Please see http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/How-to-use-JavaFileScannerContext-getSemanticModel-td5029996.html for more details. This limitation is done by SonarQube plugin packaging. I guess the error message should be mroe explicit (yes, this is an understatement).

If you want to access semantic information please use the semantic API from the tree nodes to access symbols and types.